# Clickable logo - Div as link

Tags: html

In the header of my website I have an image. I want this image to become a link.
Currently I display the image as a background for a DIV element:

```
.myheader
{  
  font-weight: bolder;
  text-transform: uppercase; 
  text-align: justify;
  background-image: url(images/back.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: top center;
  margin: auto;  
  width: 700px;
  height: 100px; 
}
```

I want the whole DIV to be clickable as a link to the homepage.

UPDATE
Okay, looking at Stack Overflow with FireBug I can see that their logo is not a background but rather an `<img>` element. Seems that this is the only option.

Comment: It is not the only option, see answers below.

Comment: Yeap excuse me for my little knowing of HTML. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`div`s cannot be made into links, they are structural elements,

The only way you could go about this is by creating a hyperlink element `a` inside the logo `div` and assigning it a class `myClass` then in a CSS give the following:

```
a.myClass {
width:700px;
height:100px;
display:block;
}
```

This should give the impression that the div is clickable by making the `a` element the same width and height as the logo `div`

Answer (score 2):

```
a.in-question {
    display:block;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
```